# Logout from google account. Call a URL in the background/in a hidden way

Tags: php, redirect, curl, logout, server-side

I need to log out the user from google apps account. Now in my application I want that when the user clicks on LOGOUT the following should happen: 
 
1. he should get logged out from Google apps account - For this I need to send a hidden request to the URL - https://mail.google.com/a/aspiringminds.in/?logout&hl=en
I am able to call this url easily. What I need is to **call this url in a hidden manner ie the user should not be redirected to this page or see this page.** This is the major part where I am stuck. I have tried curl, javascript popup window, iframe, php redirection but nothing seems to work. I think only server side request will help here like 'curl'. Pleaaassseee help !!!! 
2. If the user is successfully logged out - I need to take him to this page - `sign_in.php?logout=1` 
I have been trying to do this since the last 2 days but am unable to do so. Please help.

Comment: "Hi, I need to log out the user from google apps account" - no, you don't. Unless you are working for Google.

Comment: I think he meant log the user out from their google apps acc for his site, as the URL indicates.

Answer (score 2):

omg just use jquery like this

```
$('#logoutlink').click(function(){
    $.get('http://..............');return false;
    };);
```

that will call the url from client side but will ignore the returned data

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an iframe of size 1x1 of that url, that way the user won't even realise it.

Comment: If i use iframe, I am not able to redirect to sig_in page(sign_in.php?logout=1)..... :(  ...